# Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatareader

I am opening a data reader within another one, but when I open the second data reader and try to read the data, it says that it is closed even though I just opened it.

Here is my function:

```
protected void checkBookStockAgain()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStore"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        string selectCartString = "Select Item, Price, Quantity From ShoppingCart Where Username = @User";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectCartString, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", Session["user"].ToString());
        SqlDataReader readCart = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (readCart.Read())
        {
            string selectBookInfo = "Select Quantity from BookInfo where Title = @Title";
            SqlCommand bookInfoQuantitycmd = new SqlCommand(selectBookInfo, conn);
            bookInfoQuantitycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", readCart["Item"]);
            SqlDataReader quantityReader = bookInfoQuantitycmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (quantityReader.Read())
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(readCart["Quantity"]) > Convert.ToInt32(quantityReader["Quantity"]))
                {
                    updateCart = false;
                    quantityReader.Close();
                    readCart.Close();
                    conn.Close();
                }
                else if (Convert.ToInt32(readCart["Quantity"]) < Convert.ToInt32(quantityReader["Quantity"]))
                {
                    updateCart = true;
                    invQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(quantityReader["Quantity"].ToString()) - Convert.ToInt32(readCart["Quantity"].ToString());
                    quantityReader.Close();
                    readCart.Close();
                    conn.Close();
                }
                else if (Convert.ToInt32(readCart["Quantity"]) == Convert.ToInt32(quantityReader["Quantity"]))
                {
                    updateCart = true;
                    removeBookFromStore(readCart);
                    quantityReader.Close();
                    readCart.Close();
                    conn.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    quantityReader.Close();
                    readCart.Close();
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The error given states "Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed" and the error occurs when trying to run the while loop through quantityReader. As a side note, I've enabled MARS (Multiple Active Results Sets) in my connection string.

Comment: You have a `while` loop, but always close the reader on the first loop. maybe you just need `if(quantityReader.Read())`?

Comment: As Rhumborl started, the reader is closed then the loop is hit one more time causing the error. You can use a do/while or read once.

Comment: As a side note, you should learn about #1: SQL JOIN and #2 USING statement on IDisposable objects.

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much!